# vagrant unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input

Tags: php, ruby, vagrant

Please help me. I can't solve this problem
When I run vagrant it says me:
Vagrant error: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input

Code:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-

dir = File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__))

require 'yaml'
require "#{dir}/puphpet/ruby/deep_merge.rb"
require "#{dir}/puphpet/ruby/to_bool.rb"

configValues = YAML.load_file("#{dir}/puphpet/config.yaml")

provider = ENV['VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER'] ? ENV['VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER'] : 'local'
if File.file?("#{dir}/puphpet/config-#{provider}.yaml")
  custom = YAML.load_file("#{dir}/puphpet/config-#{provider}.yaml")
  configValues.deep_merge!(custom)
end

if File.file?("#{dir}/puphpet/config-custom.yaml")
  custom = YAML.load_file("#{dir}/puphpet/config-custom.yaml")
  configValues.deep_merge!(custom)
end

data = configValues['vagrantfile']

Vagrant.require_version '>= 1.8.1'

domains = {
  frontend: 'shop-frontend.com',
  backend:  'shop-backend.com',
  static:   'static.shop-frontend.com'
}

config = {
  local: './vagrant/config/vagrant-local.yml',
  example: './vagrant/config/vagrant-local.example.yml'
}

end
```

Comment: Can you please post full backtrace errors  other required files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, what does the last `end` ends? Nothing in your script